# Spring cloud with Eureka - Eureka Web UI URL

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, netflix, netflix-eureka

I have Eureka setup with my spring boot application, and Eureka has a neat web UI built in which I like

Here's my config in `application.yml`

```
server:
  port: 8081
management:
  context_path: /admin    

## EUREKA CONFIG ##
eureka:  
  instance:
    hostname: localhost    
  metadataMap:
    instanceId: ${spring.application.name}:${spring.application.instance_id:${random.value}}    
  client:
    registerWithEureka: true
    fetchRegistry: true
    server:
      waitTimeInMsWhenSyncEmpty: 0
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${server.port}/eureka/
```

However, the web UI shows up on my eureka server at

```
http://localhost:8081/
```

is there a way to change the url of the web ui only to something like

```
http://localhost:8081/eurekawebui
```

Thanks

Comment: not sure if this is what you are asking.  You could add server.context-path = /eurekawebui

Comment: @ccit-spence  Technically that does answer my question, but it doesn't exactly do what I was trying to do.  I was trying to have a single spring boot server that hosted a website and on that same server have the eureka server + its web ui running.  this was to have a simplified setup (1 less server).  changing the server context doesn't let me do this unfortunetely .

Comment: You could move Eureka to a Docker container.  Throwing that out in case we are talking physical servers.  Depending on the number of supporting API instances in the config.  Eureka may need a little more power.  Another suggestion is to have 2 Eureka instances since it is critical for the overall application.  In the event Eureka goes down, you will survive for a short period of time based on client caches. If something changes the clients discovery will fail without a backup Eureka instance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can set `eureka.dashboard.path=/eurekawebui`.  It defaults to `/`.

Comment: The default URI for Eureka Web UI was /. So if my app is running on port say 8761 then the uri would be http://localhost:8761